# List of EU Regulations

Tags: european-union

Is there a website where I can view the list of EU regulations (not directives)?

I can get a view of directives by searching for the UK Statutory Instruments that implement them, but would like to better understand the volume of EU regulations (which, AFAIK have no correspondent in national law).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website of the European Union gives you all legislative acts.

You can click [here](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/collection/eu-law/legislation/recent.html?locale=en). This gives you a directory of all legal acts. In the search function you can filter by regulation, directive, etc.

Comment: Thank you. To help me check my search filter, are there circa 149,000 regulations (as reported by my search via the link provided)?

Comment: That's the number I'm getting, but I'm not an expert on that filter.